# grep from bottom to top of a file

Tags: command-line, grep

what is the option with grep or egrep through which we can search from bottom to up of a file
normally they works in the top to bottom

Answer (score 15):

```
tac your.log | grep stuff
```

Comment: Shame on Mac OS X not including that program!

Comment: You can get it throug macports (coreutils), it will be named gtac.

Answer (score 0):

If you can stand the delay, I'd consider just piping the result through the rev program.

Comment: Something along the lines of...: grep whatever | rev -

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/tac.html) is a sed implementation of reversing your file.

You can simply use it like this:

`sed -n '1! G;$ p;h' yourfile | grep search_text`

Note: `sed` option `-n` to supress automatic printing of how it is performing the reverse of your file

sed commands used: `1! G` command in `sed` is doing a reverse replacement of text except the first line into buffer, `$ p` command prints the last line, `h` commands prints the buffer

More fun stuff `sed` offers: [Examples](https://linuxconfig.org/learning-linux-commands-sed)

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash

start=10
while true
do
  if tail -${start} "file" | grep -q "search" ;then
    tail -${start} "file" | grep "search"
    exit
  else
    ((start+=10))
  fi
done
```

Comment: That looks like a VERY slow solution, and only reverses by chunks.